# How to open POST url in device browser from React native application

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-application, inappbrowser

I have a shopping website where user can add items to the user's cart. But in the checkout process, I want the user to navigate in my website with the user's cart token. I want to open URL in Device browser from the react-native application with post data.

Comment: You can try it with react-native-webview. WebView supports POST method with url.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called `Linking` you could use.
You can open the url like so:

```
Linking.openURL('<insert-url-here');
```

This will open the URL in the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to `Linking` documentation, you can't pass any POST data with the url. You can only send POST data with fetch. You will have to find another way for this to work.

You could definitely just send your token with GET data:

```
Linking.openURL('https://yoururl.com/?cart_token=[token]');
```

Comment: i have tried this, but I want to send data using post method, I do not want to pass my token in URL. Using this function how can i send data in request body.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to check if any installed app can handle a given URL
>   beforehand you can call:

```
Linking.canOpenURL(url)
  .then((supported) => {
    if (!supported) {
      console.log("Can't handle url: " + url);
    } else {
      return Linking.openURL(url);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#opening-external-links

Comment: i have tried this, but I want to send data using post method, I do not want to pass my token in URL. Using this function how can i send data in request body.